# Пропали все File Templat'ы Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, settings

День добрый. В IDEA при попытке создать новый класс появляется ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заглянул в шаблоны, и там, где должны быть шаблоны создания классов и прочего добра - пустота.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал полную переустановку IDEA, 2 раза.
Пробовал скидывать настройки File and Templates с другого компа - тоже не помогло. 
Подскажите решение пожалуйста.

Comment: Кликаешь на src правой кнопкой затем Mark Directory as / Sources Root

Comment: nope. не сработало

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то в идее есть дебаг режим с логами. Попробуй шлепнуть директорию с пользовательскими настройками (в $HOME которые). Шаблоны кэшируются при запуске идеи и возможно в идее проглатывается исключение если например нет прав на чтение файлов шаблонов. Но по идее в логах исключение быть должно или как минимум в трее в нижнем правом углу красная иконка с восклицательным знаком. Ещё возможно плагины так могут нерв портить, если с версиями трабла.